# Enabling PAE on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, boot, dell-latitude, lubuntu, pae

When I try to enable the PAE switch in `boot.ini` nothing happens. I save the file and reboot, then reboot the system again to install Lubuntu and it says that there isn't PAE enabled. To be more specific, I'm running it on a Dell Latitide D600 and editing `boot.ini` through Windows XP SP3

Comment: Enabling PAE in the Windows bootloader won't affect Linux... unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enable PAE in Linux via the PAE kernel, or via BIOS, if such a setting exists. `boot.ini` route affects only Windows XP, not other OS running outside it.

Comment: If I recall correctly, modern 32 bit versions of ubuntu come with the PAE kernel by default.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah, so do I, but mentioned it for sake of completeness

Comment: So, if lubuntu says PAE is not enabled, and its a newer version, its quite likely the system itself not having it enabled